# Type aliases in C#

Tags: c#, .net, overloading, typedef, implicit-conversion

I'm looking for ways to add syntactic sugar to a project, and am considering adding an `Alias` class, that is a bit reminiscent of `typedef` in C++, with significant differences.  The purposes of it are to provide a way to easily create shortened aliases for complex typenames, and to allow more flexibility with method overloading. It would look something like this:

### The Class

```
public class Alias<T>
{
    private T Data { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator T(Alias<T> rhs)
    {
        return rhs.Data;
    }

    public static implicit operator Alias<T>(T rhs)
    {
        return new Alias<T> { Data = rhs };
    }

    // Dereferencing operator
    public static T operator ~(Alias<T> rhs)
    {
        return rhs.Data;
    }
}
```

### Use Case 1: Shorten complex type names

```
// Declare alias somewhere for a cumbersome type, 
// like a dictionary of dictionaries
class UserFields : Alias<Dictionary<string, string>> {}
class UserInfos : Alias<Dictionary<int, UserFields>> {}

// Now use it
UserFields fields = new UserFields();
UserInfos infos = new UserInfos();
(~infos)[0] = fields;
```

### Use Case 2: Method overloading

```
// Declare some aliases
class UserId : Alias<Int64> {}
class ProductId : Alias<Int64> {}

// Now we can distinguish between them, though they
// are both Int64's
public void DoSomething(UserId userId) { ... }
public void DoSomething(ProductId productId) { ... }
```

---

The examples are contrived, but hopefully illustrate my intentions.  I'm afraid this might end up being hacky, with unexpected consequences. What are some of the pitfalls and problems with using the `Alias` class as described?

Comment: Your `Alias` class isn't even slighly like using `typedef`, IMO. It would be closer if it were a struct rather than a class, admittedly. It's not really clear why you want to use this at all, but I'd *strongly* discourage you from doing so.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I had the feeling it was a bad idea, hence the question, but I'm still hoping answers will shed more light on *why* it's a bad idea.

Comment: One other problem with this that occurs to me... The implicit operator from `T` to `Alias<T>` is useless (or at least, it is not really *implicit*), because if you have some class `A` that inherits from `Alias<T>`, you still won't be able to implicitly convert `T` to `A`, because that would require an explicit downcast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of why it's a bad idea:

- It isn't *really* an alias. Anywhere that doesn't let you use the implicit conversions won't work pleasantly with this.
- You're using a `class`, which means you need to allocate an extra object every time you use this. It would be cleaner to use a `struct`
- You're overloading the `~` operator for no particularly obvious reason - and certainly not in a way which is similar to the normal meaning of the operator in C#
- You're using subclassing in a way which really *isn't* anything to do with specialization

You can *consider* using `using` directives as aliases:

```
using FooString = System.String;
...
FooString x = "whatever";
```

... with the disadvantage that the "alias" here is only applicable within the same source.

Personally if I wanted a mapping from string to string, I'd just use `Dictionary<string, string>`. Every C# developer wortht their salt would instantly know what it meant, there'd be nothing "odd" in terms of debugging, no extra allocations etc.

Comment: Another serious problem is that the aliased class wouldn't have access to non-default constructors. For example, he couldn't write `UserFields myUserFields = new UserFields(100);` to create a dictionary with an initial capacity of 100.

Comment: @JimMischel: True - you'd need `UserFields myUserFields = new Dictionary<string, string>(100)` so the aliasing really "bleeds".

Comment: Thanks! I'll avoid it.  But to clarify, an alias for a `Dictionary<string, string>` wasn't the point.  The point was to alias a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>`, which I do think would be nice to be able to do (somehow).  I'm not a fan of `using`, since they can't build off of each other (you have to fully namespace everything), and (as you said) they are per source.

Comment: @Eric: In that case I would create a new class which used *composition* to hide the `Dictionary<string, string>` - you quite possibly don't want *all* the operations on a `Dictionary<string, string>` available on a `UserFields` object anyway, for example.